# When I unplug my USB HD via "Safely Remove" my system hangs

Tags: 11.10

Mother Board is (DG41RQ), Processor (2.93 GHZ) , RAM (4 GB) , My External Hard Drive is Samsung (1.5 TB)..When i unplugged (Safely Remove) my system got Hanged . I am using Ubuntu 11.10 DVD version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that has been fixed in a kernel upgrade. The upgrade has not yet been released though likely will be in the next couple of weeks or so. (currently in oneiric-proposed for testing of the 'whole' of the upgrade, not just this one issue.

bug specific to this issue
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/844957

tracking bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/868628